# Identify game: Intergalactic United Nations

Tags: identify-this-game

Trying to identify a game I played at a convention a couple years ago. (No, it was *not* Diplomacy.) It was a fairly light and lighthearted game where you play the “Space UN” and debate what laws to pass. Every player has a species — one guy was the “Klingons” (but not), and I was the mind-controlling space slugs.

The name of the game was an outer-spacey pun of some sort — on “bureaucracy”, or “diplomacy” or the like.

You drew cards to determine what legislation to debate — card would have blanks in the topic, and you would draw from a second deck to fill in the blanks(?) — then two players would debate that legislation. Then other players voted who won each debate. One of the debates I recall was regulations on how many prosthetic limbs a being was allowed to add to their body (insert “arms control” joke here).

I believe it was a relatively recent game at the time, but it could have been a reprint of an older one. I probably played it three or four years ago

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just did an advanced search for **party games + science fiction** (weight < 2) and [Cosmocracy](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/203408/cosmocracy) was 10th on the list.

Comment: good find.  I could only think of Democrazy from the 'pun based title'. but that wasn't set in space.

Comment: That’s it. Upvote also for saying *how* you found it

Comment: BGG is still useful for the occasional query ;)

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 still? What's more useful than BGG?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh - for being a database and an ideological leper colony, nothing!